# Access and move modelview OpenGL 3.2

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to create a snake game. I managed to create my field with of squares and I drew my red snake as a square with this:

```
void drawSnake()
{
    mat4 modelView;

    modelView = Translate(0,0,0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Right now I'm not storing my snake anywhere when I draw it. I am thinking maybe I can store the modelView as an object and then translate the object around, which would be the snake moving around. But maybe this is a stupid way to do it, so I thought I would ask for some better ways.

```
Vertex rectangleData1[rectangleSize] = {
        { vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( 1.0, -1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( 1.0,  1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2( 1.0,  1.0 ), color1 },
        { vec2(-1.0, 1.0 ), color1 }
    };
```

Comment: But you must have the snake vertices somewhere right..?

Comment: Yeah I have glDrawArrays to draw my 6 vertices which make up my snake square.

Comment: Yes, but you're calling `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`  The 0 means that you have a vertex array somewhere?

Comment: I just edited the code to show you the vertex array. The 0 means the starting index for that array I guess.

Comment: for a large and static dataset based model, it is surely more convenient to use a matrix to define the movements of the model. In your case, you should not be afraid of updating the data by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to assume that using and modifying a matrix per game object is the proper technique for transition said game objects. In graphics, these matrices are usually referred to as 'Model' or 'World' matrices. When using OpenGL for 3D applications, you can additionally provide View and Projection matrices to your shader program (only one each used per render) to allow for a realistic, modifyable,  presentation of your world space. This camera-like presentation of your world space is called a viewing frustum.